# Constructor Chain

Tags: java, constructor

Why do we use this form? (it's on a course on plural sight for Java)

```
public MathEquation(char opCode)
    {
        this.opCode = opCode;
    }

public MathEquation(char opCode , double leftVal , double rightVal)
    {
        this(opCode);
        this.leftVal = leftVal;
        this.rightVal = rightVal;
    }
```

and why not this?

```
public MathEquation(char opCode , double leftVal , double rightVal)
    {
        this.opCode = opCode
        this.leftVal = leftVal;
        this.rightVal = rightVal;    
    }
```

Comment: Because the class can be constructed two different ways depending on what arguments are available?

Comment: And to make clear that there are two "usual" ways to construct it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because if, for some reason, you need to do something more with the opCode (like turning it to uppercase before storing it, or check it's in some range, or anything like that), you won't have to repeat that code in the two constructors. One will simply invoke the code already written in the other.

This general principle is called DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself.

Note that it's often being made in the other direction: the simplest constructor calls the most complex one, specifying what default values to pass for the missing arguments:

```
public MathEquation(char opCode) {
    this(opCode, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

Comment: so i can just write the 2nd constructor to avoid repetition but we use this form of chaining to allow us to ... change opCode into "OpCode" ?
and what do u mean by Range ( sorry am fairly new to programming :D )

Comment: No. Suppose the opCode passed as argument is "p", and you actually want to store it as "P" (i.e. turning it to uppercase before storing it). Or suppose the caller is only supposed to pass values between "a" and "z" (i.e. in some range of values) and the constructor needs to check that the value is indeed in that range of value.

Answer (score 2):

The point is: you want to minimize the amount of *different* work that constructors do.

And from that point of view the optimal solution would be that the one arg constructor invokes the 3 arg constructor (making it also explicit what default values should be used for the other two arguments)! When you do that only one constructor does something - whereas in your example the 3 arg constructor does something *and* calls the other one.

Meaning: neither of the forms used in the question are ideal.

Comment: okay what's the ideal form ? (note that : the constructors used above r for illustration of Constructor chaining )

Comment: @ShaDiliX The answer is right there, in front of you, in the 6 lines of the answer: *the optimal solution would be that the one arg constructor invokes the 3 arg constructor*. Read carefully.

Comment: but he said neither of the forms used in the question are ideal ... that's why i asked

Comment: Does any of the two forms in your question have the one-arg constructor invoke the 3-args constructor? No. One doesn't use constructor chaining at all, and the other calls the one-arg constructor from the 3-args one. Again, read carefully.

Comment: Yep sry 
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

To comply with

S - Single-responsibility principle
O - Open-closed principle

the below constructor is responsible for only one operation and if in future you want to extend the functionality, you can easily do it.

```java
public MathEquation(char opCode)
{
    this.opCode = opCode;
    //new functionality 
}
```